# Process Postfix Expressions in Java

Tags: java, expression, postfix-operator

I am trying to create a program that will take the input of a postfix expression, evaluate that the operands are valid and apply the operator to those operands.

I am aware of the `Scanner` class to take the input I have no problem with this. Currently I have:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    String equation;

    System.out.println("Please enter a postfix expression:");

    equation = scan.nextLine();
```

I now need to process what the user has typed. I'm after the easier solution to this problem.

Comment: What approach have you tried already?

Answer (score 2):

Use `java.util.Stack`. The example below serves just to demonstrate the use of `Stack`. There's no checking on the validity of the postfix expression.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<Integer>();

    System.out.println("Please enter a postfix expression:");

    String equation = scan.nextLine();

    String[] terms = equation.split(" ");

    for (String s : terms ) {

        if (s.equals("+")) stack.push(stack.pop() + stack.pop());
        else if (s.equals("-")) stack.push(-stack.pop() + stack.pop());
        else if (s.equals("*")) stack.push(stack.pop() * stack.pop());
        else if (s.equals("/")) {
            int a = stack.pop(); 
            int b = stack.pop(); 
            stack.push( b/a );
        }
        else stack.push(Integer.parseInt(s));
    }
    System.out.println("result: " + stack.pop());
}
```

For a more elaborate example take a look at http://kevinyavno.com/blog/?p=52